# grunt js minify convert unicode char

Tags: javascript, unicode, gruntjs, minify

My `script.js` file has code like this:

```
var pattern = new RegExp("^[\u0000-\u000D\u0020-\u007F\u00A1-\u00AC\u00AE-\u00FF\u0152-\u0153\u20AC\u201C\u201D\u2022]*$", "g");
```

…and when Grunt minifies it, the escape sequences (e.g. `\u00e1`) become the special characters that they stand for (e.g. `á`). I don't want the special character `á`, I want the escaped representation. What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What minifier are you using? Assuming it’s [grunt-contrib-uglify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify), make sure you’re [setting the `ascii_only` option](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify/issues/31#issuecomment-14320863).